# on click action of a button null data is getting stored in database when i try to add it through java bean

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

When I click on the button I'm getting "record saved" message on another page named "page1.html" as mentioned in JSF faces configuration file, but the record is null for string and 0 for integers. Where am I getting wrong?

my managed bean code(Inventory.java):-

```
    import java.awt.Frame;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import javax.inject.Named;
    import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    /**
     *
     * @author Pritam
     */
    @Named(value = "inventory")
    @Dependent
    public class Inventory {

        String item;
        int price, qty;

        public String getItem() {
            return item;
        }

        public void setItem(String item) {
            this.item = item;
        }

        public int getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(int price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        public int getQty() {
            return qty;
        }

        public void setQty(int qty) {
            this.qty = qty;
        }


        public Inventory() {
        }

        public String addItem()
        {
            try{
                Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/practice");
                Statement ps=con.createStatement();        
                ps.executeUpdate("insert into inv_table values('"+getItem()+"',"+getPrice()+","+getQty()+")");
                return "Success";

            }
            catch(Exception e){

                return "Failed";

            }

        }
    }
```

> this is my jsf page(MyIndex.xhtml):-

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <pre>
                Item Name:          <h:inputText id="t1" value="#{inventory.item}" size="10">
                                    </h:inputText>
                Item Price:         <h:inputText id="t2" value="#{inventory.price}" size="10">
                                        <f:convertNumber type="number"></f:convertNumber>
                                    </h:inputText>
                Item Quantity:      <h:inputText id="t3" value="#{inventory.qty}" size="10">
                                        <f:convertNumber type="number"></f:convertNumber>
                                    </h:inputText>

                                <h:commandButton id="btn"  value="add item" action="#{inventory.addItem()}">
                                </h:commandButton>

            </pre>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

JSF faces configuration file:-

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>MyIndex.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{inventory.addItem()}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>Success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>page1.html</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{inventory.addItem()}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>Failed</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>page2.html</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

Answer (score -1):

try your codes with binding="" instead of value=""

```
            Item Name:          <h:inputText id="t1" binding="#{inventory.item}" size="10">
                                </h:inputText>
            Item Price:         <h:inputText id="t2" binding="#{inventory.price}" size="10">
                                    <f:convertNumber type="number"></f:convertNumber>
                                </h:inputText>
            Item Quantity:      <h:inputText id="t3" binding="#{inventory.qty}" size="10">
                                    <f:convertNumber type="number"></f:convertNumber>
                                </h:inputText>
```

Comment: Please try yourself first before doing off as an answer.

Comment: I did it and it worked for me @BalusC

Comment: Thank you for your response. My issue is resolved when i modified faces-config.xml file using PageFlow  feature of netbeans IDE.